# how to compare two dates in stream filter in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I get two dates from a request object using stream filter. There I have to compare those objects then collect them store in list. But now i get this error. Please help me with it.

**Error:**

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean

**Code:**

```
Date checkIn = req.getCheckIn();
Date checkOut = req.getCheckOut();

List<PlaceBook> filtered = checkInVal.stream().filter(string -> 
            string.getCheckInDt().compareTo(checkIn)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use `equals` instead of `compareTo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont declare what your filter condition actually is:

```
List<PlaceBook> filtered = checkInVal.stream().filter(string -> 
        string.getCheckInDt().compareTo(checkIn) == 0 /* == 0, for example is missing*/).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

compareTo by itself returns an int value, that cannot be cast to boolean, which is required by filter.

BTW 'string' is not a good name in the filter.